# Contract execution fails with Web3 but works with Remix

Tags: web3js, contract-invocation

I am dealing with a very simple smart contract:

```
contract MyRegistry {

    struct MyEvent {
        string date; // yyyy/mm/dd
        string desc; // potentially long string
        uint count;  // <= 10000
        bool recorded;
    }

    event Record(bytes32 hash, string desc, uint count);

    function record(bytes32 hash, string date, string desc, uint count) external {
        if (registry[hash].recorded)
            throw;
        registry[hash] = MyEvent(date, desc, count, true);
    }

    mapping (bytes32 => MyEvent) public registry;
}
```

Now, when trying to call `record` method from Remix (using MetaMask), everything is ok, contract execution is successful, using the following input:

```
"10f2e5c1bacf028b41415d0868d5892218df0a4398f0f3ac729e0ac3ac6ed11a", "2016/03/21", "my long description of at least 30 chars", 9876
```

While, using web3 always fails:

```
var EthTX = require('ethereumjs-tx')
[...]
var calldata = Registry.record.getData(hash, date, desc, count)
[...]
var transaction = new EthTX({
    to: registry_address,
    gasLimit: 4000000,
    gasPrice: +web3.toWei(10, 'gwei'),
    nonce: myNonce, // previously fetched, problem is not here
    data: calldata,
})
```

**NOTE[0]:** I voluntarily omitted the JS code used to sign and send the transaction because the problem is not there. The transaction gets submitted and mined successfully. The problem is during *contract execution*.

**NOTE[1]:** I've already tried using `bytes` instead of `string` for storing *date* and *desc*, but no luck, still the same: works on Remix, does not work with Web3. Also, cannot be lack of `gas`, otherwise the same tx would fail on Remix too.

Here is the env:

- Ubuntu 16.04
- Node 7.6.0
- web3 0.18.4
- ethereumjs-tx 1.3.0
- ethereumjs-util 5.1.1
- I **must** generate and sign txs with `ethereumjs-tx`

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: update ethereumjs-tx and web3

Comment: They are both at the latest version, check it yourself: [ethereumjs-tx](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ethereumjs-tx) ,  [ethereumjs-util](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ethereumjs-util)

Comment: Try adding -   pragma solidity ^0.4.0;       to the top of the contract.

Comment: have you set your web3 provider? Try including both gas and account in your call. I am not familiar with ethereumjs-tx

Comment: you should try with web3 1.0 beta. It has better error reporting and it would allow you to get rid of 3rd party libs as there is a signing function eth.accounts.signTransaction(txObj, pkHex)